# occurrence counting in a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

> ```
>  G1  G2  G3
>   a   b   f
>   b   c   a
>   c   d   b
> ```
>
> > and a reference list:
> >      L:
> >      a
> >      b
> >      c
> >      d
> >      e
> >      f

I would like to have the following output:

> ```
> a: 2, G1,G3   (that is "a" occurs two times in G1 and in G3 column)
> b: 3, G1,G2,G3
> c: 2, G1,G2
> ```

and so on..
Can anyone help me? Sorry to bother you but I'm new in R
Thanks in advance.

Eleonora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in another way.

```
A=data.frame( G1=c("a","b","c"),  G2=c("b","c","d"),  G3=c("f","a","b"))

B= melt(as.matrix(A))
B$X2 =as.character(B$X2)
B1=table(as.matrix(A))
D=aggregate(X2~value , B, FUN=c)
D$cnt=B1[D$value]
D
```

Output is

```
  value         X2 cnt
1     a     G1, G3   2
2     b G1, G2, G3   3
3     c     G1, G2   2
4     d         G2   1
5     f         G3   1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
r <- reshape(d,varying=list(colnames(d)),direction='long',
             v.names='value',times=colnames(d),timevar='colname')

res <- by(r,r$value,FUN=function(x){unique(x$colname)})



> res

r$value: a
[1] "G1" "G3"
------------------------------------------------------------ 
r$value: b
[1] "G1" "G2" "G3"
------------------------------------------------------------ 
r$value: c
[1] "G1" "G2"
------------------------------------------------------------ 
r$value: d
[1] "G2"
------------------------------------------------------------ 
r$value: f
[1] "G3"
```

Basically `res` is a list containing for each letter, the vector of column names where the letter appears e.g.:

```
res$a : 'G1', 'G3'
res$b : 'G1', 'G2', 'G3'
...
```

If you want only the number of occurrences, you can do something like this:

```
> lapply(res,length)
$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 3

$c
[1] 2

$d
[1] 1

$f
[1] 1
```

**EDIT :**
To write `res` on a file, one way could be the following:

```
# prepare the table (data.frame) to be written
dF <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(res,function(x){list(Occur=length(x),Columns=paste(x,collapse=' '))}))
dF <- cbind(Letter=row.names(dF),dF)
# write the table to file
write.table(dF,row.names=FALSE,sep=',',file='myfile.csv')
```

File text:

```
"Letter","Occur","Columns"
"a",2,"G1 G3"
"b",3,"G1 G2 G3"
"c",2,"G1 G2"
"d",1,"G2"
"f",1,"G3"
```

Comment: @Eleonora: Just a note: what if the first row of your data.frame was: `'a' 'b' 'a'` ? In this case `'a'` would appear 2 times in G3. What is the correct count of `'a'` in this case ? 2 or 3 ? If it's the former keep the current code; if it's the latter just remove `unique` from the `by` function :)

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you very much for your help! yes, the first row of my data.frame is "a", "b", "f".  The correct count of "a" is 2 because it appears in G1 and G3 samples. As a matter of fact your code works. I just have the last question. How can I save the res as a xls or txt file? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both methods here work well already.  Just thought I'd give a little different method that I used for a similar problem.

```
#Vinux's data:
A=data.frame( G1=c("a","b","c"),  G2=c("b","c","d"),  G3=c("f","a","b"))

B <- data.frame(x=rep(colnames(A), sapply(A, length)),        #means of reshaping data
    y=c(apply(A, 2, as.character)))
C <- split(B$x, B$y)                                          #column names by value
D <- data.frame(letter=names(C), occurance=sapply(C, length)) #get occurrences
D$column <- sapply(C, as.character)                           #force vector of vectors
D[, c(1, 3, 2), ]                                             #order it
```

Which yields:

```
  letter     column occurance
a      a     G1, G3         2
b      b G1, G2, G3         3
c      c     G1, G2         2
d      d         G2         1
f      f         G3         1
```